# Android - Error in Adapter: The method getView(int, View, ViewGroup) from the type new ArrayAdapter<String>(){} is never used locally

Tags: android, adapter

In my adapter not create View. All data make from array:

```
private ArrayAdapter<String> taskAdapter(String appsArray[], String vectorNum) {

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, appsArray) {

//  The method getView(int, View, ViewGroup) from the type new ArrayAdapter<String>(){}
//  is never used locally
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            String item = getItem(position);
            String[] itemArr = item.split("::");
            String text = itemArr[0];
            String id = itemArr[1];

            // I think - error in constructor Text View
            TextView listItem = new TextView(Settings.this);

            listItem.setText(text);
            listItem.setTag(id);
            listItem.setTextSize(22);
            listItem.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
            listItem.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

            return listItem;
        }
    };

    return adapter;
}
```

Adapter working, but not use function for construction fields of data:
public View getView(.....) { .... }

Whats need change for create view ???

Comment: ah, it is a method that returns your adapter

Comment: well, try adding `@Override` annotation to the getView method

Comment: The method getView(int, View, ViewGroup) of type new ArrayAdapter<String>(){} must override or implement a supertype method

Comment: That is weird, it should find a supertype getView method to override. Did you do it like this?
             `@Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {`

Comment: your ArrayAdapter is an `android.widget.ArrayAdapter` ?

Comment: Override may add after: import android.view.ViewGroup;

Now all working good - thanks for help : - )))

Answer (score 2):

Error - completely destroyed 8 - )))

Need:

```
import android.view.ViewGroup;
```

And after @Override annotation Add and working properly.